# Make checkbox.Checked = True whose corresponding PictureBox is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have 28 CheckBoxes in a windows form. Each box has PictureBox above it. When the user clicks on a PictureBox, I want to change the BackColor of the PictureBox to green, and make its corresponding CheckBox.Checked = True

The code I am using:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click
    PictureBox1.BackColor = Color. Green 
    CheckBox1.Checked = true
```

For 28 it will be a lengthy process. Is there any easy solution?

Comment: You would have cleaner code if you put the PictureBox and the CheckBox inside a UserControl.

Comment: While there are many ways to solve this problem, I agree with @LarsTech that the best solution is to create your own control.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically add MouseClick even handlers to all your PictureBoxes in Form_Load. The event handler will parse the sender (PictureBox) and find the CheckBox based on the fact that the corresponding controls' names end in the same index. Remove the handlers when the form closes.

```
Private pictureBoxPrefix As String = "PictureBox"
Private checkBoxPrefix As String = "CheckBox"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each pb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox).Where(Function(p) p.Name.Contains(pictureBoxPrefix))
        AddHandler pb.MouseClick, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseClick
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim index = Integer.Parse(pb.Name.Replace(pictureBoxPrefix, ""))
    Dim pb = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim cb = CType(Me.Controls.Find($"{checkBoxPrefix}{index}", True).First(), CheckBox)
    pb.BackColor = Color.Green
    cb.Checked = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    For Each pb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox).Where(Function(p) p.Name.Contains(pictureBoxPrefix))
        RemoveHandler pb.MouseClick, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseClick
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Load() event of your form, use Controls.Find() to get a reference to both the PictureBoxes and CheckBoxes.  Store the CheckBox reference in the Tag() property of each PictureBox.  Wire up the Click() event of you PB.  In that event, change the color of the PB, then retrieve the CheckBox from the Tag() property and check the box as well:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i As Integer = 1 To 28
        Dim PB As PictureBox = Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
        Dim CB As CheckBox = Me.Controls.Find("CheckBox" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(PB) AndAlso Not IsNothing(CB) Then
            PB.Tag = CB
            CB.Tag = PB
            AddHandler PB.Click, AddressOf PB_Click
            AddHandler CB.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CB_CheckedChanged
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(pb.Tag, CheckBox)
    If pb.BackColor.Equals(Color.Green) Then
        pb.BackColor = Color.Empty
        cb.Checked = False
    Else
        pb.BackColor = Color.Green
        cb.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CB_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(cb.Tag, PictureBox)
    pb.BackColor = If(cb.Checked, Color.Green, Color.Empty)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @Idle_Mind, it's working properly, i want ask, is there a way to make checkbox. Checked = false & picturebox. BackColor to empty if user again clicks that picturebox

Comment: @Idle_Mind I know you better than this lol `Dim cb As CheckBox = pb.Tag`, turn `Option Strict On`... it needs to be casted from an object.

Comment: pretty clever to hold the cb in pb tag.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ maybe better to hold the cb.Name in tag which was my first idea, but really dont need that either. Pretty sure my answer would work out as is assuming a 1-1 pb/cb control correspondence

Comment: Agreed, don't need any of it; theres more than one way to do this.

Comment: I love seeing what people come up with.

Comment: Also modified to also change the PBs when the CBs are changed.