# Vb.net Change the back color of picturebox whose corresponding checkbox.checked = true

Tags: vb.net

I have 20 checkboxes, with 20 picture boxes above them.
I want to change the back color of those picture boxes whose corresponding checkbox is set to checked = true in form load.

I have used code:

```
CheckBox1.CheckedChanged 
PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.brown
```

For 20 checkboxes, it will be lengthy process is there any shorter solution so that it changes back color of only those picture boxes whose corresponding checkbox is `checked = true`  in form load

Comment: The ideas in [Make checkbox.Checked = True whose corresponding PictureBox is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260470/make-checkbox-checked-true-whose-corresponding-picturebox-is-clicked) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You only want this to be checked in form load that makes it even simpler..

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For i = 1 To 20
        Dim cbx As CheckBox = Me.Controls.Find("CheckBox" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
        Dim pbx As PictureBox = Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
        If cbx.Checked = True Then
            pbx.BackColor = Color.Brown
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @DivyaTiwari If this has solved your problem please check the answer as answered

Comment: @DivyaTiwari If your CheckBox/PictureBox layout is similar to the image above, then you might want to consider creating a composite control that has the Picture Box and Checkbox inside it. I think it would create a really simple end solution, but will take a lot of work/code to get to that point beforehand